# Use batch file to run scripts one at a time using conditional statement

Tags: windows, oracle, batch-file, cmd, sqlplus

I have many scripts saved in a folder and are to be run by a batch file one at a time based on hierarchy. I have developed the simple batch file;

```
sqlplus username/password@database
@/apps/Batch/script_1.txt
mkdir Results
move "script_1.txt" Results
```

At the end of the run, the script_1.txt is moved to another folder.
I have other scripts - script_2.txt, script_3.txt, etc - but I'd like to have a scenario where running the batch file executes the foremost file by hierarchy only, i.e. running the batch file again will execute script_2.txt and so on.

Is there any statement that could help solve this?

Comment: Does the provided _simple batch file_ work as expected?

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't. I ran the lines in cmd and they worked independently and I thought bring them together in a batch file will make give same results. Now I have a new challenge. Any help with any of the challenges?

Comment: Maybe with `sqlplus username/password@database @/apps/Batch/script_1.txt` in one line it could work for a particular `script_1.txt`?

Comment: Thanks JosefZ, but it doesn't  continue the command to make the "Results" folder and move script_1.txt to same. Is it possible to have the commands in same batch file?

Comment: Add `pause` command to the very end of your batch script and show error message(s) by using [edit] button (follow a [mcve] rules). I guess `The system cannot find the file specified`. Try `move "\apps\batch\script_1.txt" Results`

Comment: Ok, thanks though it still didn't work. It just runs the SQL bit of the command and just stays there waiting for the next command. I have to find a way to exit the DB and return to the root directory before making a new folder or moving the files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a FOR to loop through all the files in your directory, run them in SQLPlus and move them to a different folder.
For example, if I have a run.cmd as follows:

```
@echo off
for %%i in (*.sql) do (sqlplus siu/siu@middle_svil @%%i
IF NOT EXIST "Results" mkdir "Results"
move %%i Results
)
```

and a set of 3 SQL scripts script_1, script_2, script_3 like the following:

**script_1.sql:**

```
set serveroutput on
prompt this is script 1
exit
```

**script_2.sql:**

```
set serveroutput on
prompt this is script 2
exit
```

**script_3.sql:**

```
set serveroutput on
prompt this is script 3
exit
```

This is what I have at the beginning:

```
D:\test>dir

23/03/2017  09:28    <DIR>          .
23/03/2017  09:28    <DIR>          ..
23/03/2017  09:28    <DIR>          Results
23/03/2017  09:24               127 run.cmd
22/03/2017  14:09                50 script_1.sql
22/03/2017  14:08                50 script_2.sql
22/03/2017  14:13                50 script_3.sql
               4 File            277 byte
```

The I run the script:

```
D:\test>run

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.2.0 Production on Gio Mar 23 09:28:34 2017

Copyright (c) 1982, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options

this is script 1
Disconnected from Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options
        1 file spostato/i.

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.2.0 Production on Gio Mar 23 09:28:35 2017

Copyright (c) 1982, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options

this is script 2
Disconnected from Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options
        1 file spostato/i.

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.2.0 Production on Gio Mar 23 09:28:36 2017

Copyright (c) 1982, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options

this is script 3
Disconnected from Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options
        1 file spostato/i.
```

As you can see, the 3 sql script have run and the files have been moved in the new directory.

In fact:

```
D:\test>dir


23/03/2017  09:28    <DIR>          .
23/03/2017  09:28    <DIR>          ..
23/03/2017  09:28    <DIR>          Results
23/03/2017  09:24               127 run.cmd
               1 File            127 byte

D:\test>cd results

D:\test\Results>dir

23/03/2017  09:28    <DIR>          .
23/03/2017  09:28    <DIR>          ..
22/03/2017  14:09                50 script_1.sql
22/03/2017  14:08                50 script_2.sql
22/03/2017  14:13                50 script_3.sql
               3 File            150 byte

D:\test\Results>
```

If you need to run only one script at a time you can add a GOTO in the script to exit after having run the sql script:

```
@echo off
for %%i in (*.sql) do (sqlplus siu/siu@middle_svil @%%i
IF NOT EXIST "Results" mkdir "Results"
move %%i Results
goto :end
)
:end
```

Comment: Thanks, but this only runs the sql script up to
    "for %%i in (*.sql) do (sqlplus user/password@DB @%%i"
What happens is that after logging in to the DB and executing the sql statement, it has to exit the DB and return to the directory to make a folder or move files. Adding 
    "quit pause"
does not work too. I'd like to have the commands in a single batch file that logs into the DB, runs the query, exit the DB, creates a folder in the directory and moves the sql script into the folder.

Comment: If you put an exit at the end of every sql script, this will pick the first script, connect to DBm run the script; the sql script will close the DB connectiob with an exit command, thus returning the control to the batch. Now the batch will create the dir, move the file and then go to the next sql script.

Comment: Alright. I got this bit sorted. The other part is that I don't intend to run the 3 scripts at same time. Running the .cmd file should preferentially pick the script_1.sql only by hierarchy, execute it, create a new folder and move same to the folder. Running the .cmd file again should execute script_2 because it'd be the foremost in hierarchy, create a new folder and move. I have tried using the FOR loop or set some variable increment but can't seem to get it sorted. Any ideas?

Comment: Adding something to stop the batch after having run the SQL script should be enough. I just edited to show you

Comment: Thanks a lot. Works really fine. Just the final bit - is it possible that anytime the .cmd is executed, a new folder is created with a suffix like _1, _2, etc. In essence, running the cmd first time gives folder "Results" with Scripts_1 moved into it, 2nd time will create Results_1 folder and scripts_2 moved in and so on...

Comment: Thanks @Aleksej, was able to find my way around with your assistance. Finally decided to move all files into a single folder and rename them as they are moved serially: 
[link](https://www.experts-exchange.com/viewCodeSnippet.jsp?codeSnippetId=20-38832723-1)